# Google Web search API (not custom search)

Tags: google-api, google-search, google-search-api

So google pulled the SOAP API back in 2006, and depreciated the REST API last year. Even though the REST api still works fine, I was wondering if anyone here knows an alternative for the web search. I am not talking about Custom search API (that thing is horrible with a 100 queries/day limit).

Also, I am currently using the REST api for a custom application. I have noticed mixed (and very unreliable) results if I pass search operators such as inurl: or site: with my queries. Does anyone know if these even work with the REST Api?

Comment: would you please share your findings related to this subject if you have any. I also have a similar problem at the time being.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search parameters do work for Googles deprecated REST API. But search results often do not equal the ones from a regular Google search. Most likely because the two do not (and never will) use the same data index.

- [*YAHOOs BOSS*](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) could be a (non-free) alternative
- [*Microsoft*](http://www.bing.com/developers/) does offer a simple and free restful API for BING